# How to get the color code of two overlapping colors in css?

Tags: css, sass, colors

I have two colors: `#FFF8F6` and `#AD3300`. `#AD3300` can also be written `rgba(173, 51, 0,  1)`.
I would like to overlay the second color (at 14% opacity) on top of the first to get a third color. So below `#FFF8F6` and above `rgba(173,51,0, 0.14)`.

[image: Overlapping colors image]

Is it possible to get this *color code* (the one in the box with the red border) with some function of **SASS** or **CSS**?

For the `backgroud` I can use:

```css
linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(173, 51, 0, 0, 0.14), rgba(173, 51, 0, 0.14)), #FFF8F6;
```

for the `color` property how can I do it?

Comment: you can refer to this question : https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/93450/overlap-rgb-values-to-produce-a-single-color
and use `calc` css func to compute the response

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it turns out you can with raw CSS!

You can use [color-mix()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color-mix)

I used the line below to calculate the color combination:

```css
background: color-mix(in srgb, #FFF8F6, #AD3300 14%);
```

With `#FFF8F6` as youyr first color, and `#AD3300 14%` as your second color, where it is broken down by the color given and its opacity.

I tried using `rgba(173, 51, 0, 0.14)` but the mix didn't come out right.

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  /* border: 1px solid gray; */
}

.box1 {
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  background: #FFF8F6;
}

.box1 div {}

.box2 {
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;
  background: #AD330024;
}

.box2 div {
  margin: 160px 0 0 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.box3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 250px;
  background: color-mix(in srgb, #FFF8F6, #AD3300 14%);
}

.box3 div {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box1">
  <div>#FFF8F6</div>
</div>
<div class="box box2">
  <div>#AD330024<br/>(rgba(173, 51, 0, 0.14))</div>
</div>
<div class="box box3">
  <div>color-mix</div>
</div>
```

Note also that this is [widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color-mix#browser_compatibility) with the current exceptions being:

1. Opera (experimental feature
2. Opera Android
3. Samsung Internet